# SIM800L Email fail (DNS resolve error)

Tags: dns, iot, gsm, at-command, telecommunication

When I try to send/receive emails the SIM800L GSM module always responds: +POP3IN: 62 (Which means DNS resolve error)

What could be wrong here?

I have tried 3 different service providers, 3 different email servers, and 2 different SIM800 modules with different firmware.

See the command history here:
[history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0E1M2.png)

```
20.08.2017 16:03:24.15 [TX] - AT+CREG?

20.08.2017 16:03:24.17 [RX] - 
+CREG: 0,1

OK

20.08.2017 16:04:07.01 [TX] - AT+CGATT?

20.08.2017 16:04:07.03 [RX] - 
+CGATTT: 1

OK

20.08.2017 16:04:26.98 [TX] - AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"

20.08.2017 16:04:27.02 [RX] - 
OK

20.08.2017 16:04:29.37 [TX] - AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","internet"

20.08.2017 16:04:29.40 [RX] - 
OK

20.08.2017 16:04:39.69 [TX] - AT+SAPBR=1,1

20.08.2017 16:04:40.36 [RX] - 
OK

20.08.2017 16:04:42.78 [TX] - AT+SAPBR=2,1

20.08.2017 16:04:42.80 [RX] - 
+SAPBR: 1,1,"10.142.235.73"

OK

20.08.2017 16:04:47.32 [TX] - AT+EMAILCID=1

20.08.2017 16:04:47.35 [RX] - 
OK

20.08.2017 16:04:48.43 [TX] - AT+EMAILTO=30

20.08.2017 16:04:48.45 [RX] - 
OK

20.08.2017 16:04:53.42 [TX] -AT+POP3SRV="mail.baumtronics.com","xxx@baumtronics.com","",110

20.08.2017 16:04:53.46 [RX] - 
OK

20.08.2017 16:05:07.55 [TX] - AT+EMAILSSL?

20.08.2017 16:05:07.57 [RX] - 
+EEMAILSSL: 0

OK

20.08.2017 16:05:14.70 [TX] - AT+POP3IN

20.08.2017 16:05:14.72 [RX] - 
OK

20.08.2017 16:05:15.74 [RX] - 
+POP3IN: 62

20.08.2017 16:06:04.97 [TX] - AT+POP3SRV="s10-london.accountservergroup.com","xxx@baumtronics.com","xxx",995

20.08.2017 16:06:05.03 [RX] - 
OK

20.08.2017 16:06:16.86 [TX] - AT+EMAILSSL=1

20.08.2017 16:06:16.87 [RX] - 
OK

20.08.2017 16:06:20.76 [TX] - AT+POP3IN

20.08.2017 16:06:20.77 [RX] - 
OK

20.08.2017 16:06:21.52 [RX] - 
+POP3IN: 62
```

Comment: What happens if you use the IP address directly instead?

Comment: Its the same. DNS resolve error. I wonder if anybody can report working email with SIM800 at all? All working examples are are for SIM900.